# Can sub-folders be created on the Explorer context "send to" menu

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu, send-to

I have many "send to" destinations. I would like to create sub-folders in the "Send to" folder. Is this possible? When I try, it will only create a real folder in the SendTo folder.

I want selecting an item from the "Send to" context menu to expand out into a list of SendTo destinations for that group.

Comment: This is one of those things you never realised you wanted until you find out it's probably not possible. I hope you find an answer!

Comment: @Psycogeek - Thank you for your interest in this question. I hope some creative answer will appear.

Comment: May some savior write a shell extension for you...

Comment: It would be nice if there were a concrete answer to this question.  Is this request possible in Windows 10?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An alternative approach for your reference:

[image: menu]

Save followings as `*.reg` and import to registry (adapted from [Sully@Wilders Security](http://www.wilderssecurity.com/threads/windows-7-cascading-menus.314115/))

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu]
"Icon"="shell32.dll,43"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1]
"MUIVerb"="Text Editor"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item1]
"MUIVerb"="Notepad++"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item1\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\npp\\notepad++.exe %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item2]
"MUIVerb"="Sublime Text"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item2\command]
@="C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe %1"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu2]
"MUIVerb"="Audio"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu2\shell\item1]
"MUIVerb"="Audacity"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu2\shell\item1\command]
@="audacity.exe %1"
```

**References**
[AskVG](http://www.askvg.com/add-cascading-menus-for-your-favorite-programs-in-windows-7-desktop-context-menu/)
[Directory Opus Resource Centre](https://resource.dopus.com/viewtopic.php?t=25257)

---

Addendum: Pseudo-Folder menu

[image: menu]

Save as `C:\copy.js`

```
function fnCopyHereJ(src, dest) {
    var objShell = new ActiveXObject("shell.application");
    var objFolder = objShell.NameSpace(dest);

    if (objFolder) {
        objFolder.CopyHere(src);
    } else {
        WScript.echo("Invalid Folder: "+dest);
    }
}

args = WScript.Arguments;
fnCopyHereJ(args(0), args(1));
```

Import to registry

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu]
"Icon"="shell32.dll,43"
"Subcommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1]
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-113"
"MUIVerb"="Picture"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item1]
"Icon"="shell32.dll,3"
"MUIVerb"="Folder 1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item1\command]
@="wscript C:\\copy.js %1 C:\\Users\\01\\Pictures"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item2]
"Icon"="shell32.dll,3"
"MUIVerb"="Folder 2"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu1\shell\item2\command]
@="wscript C:\\copy.js %1 \"C:\\New Folder\""


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu2]
"Icon"="imageres.dll,-108"
"MUIVerb"="Music"
"SubCommands"=""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu2\shell\item1]
"Icon"="shell32.dll,3"
"MUIVerb"="Folder 1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\My Menu\shell\menu2\shell\item1\command]
@="wscript C:\\copy.js %1 C:\\Users\\01\\Music"


[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\My Menu]
"Icon"="shell32.dll,43"
"ExtendedSubCommandsKey"="*\\shell\\My Menu"
```

**References**
[Invoke Windows copy from PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759980/invoke-windows-copy-from-powershell)
[Folder.CopyHere method (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[Cascading context menus via static registry entries and ExtendedSubCommandsKey](http://io-repo.blogspot.com/2011/05/cascading-context-menus-via-static.html)

Comment: This is a good idea. It appears that these are all used to start programs (ie. Notepad++, Audacity, etc.). Can any of the targets simply be a directory to where the file is copied? It is still not the same as using the "Send to" item that people already know. I need to share these with a group, 15-20 people.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think it can. Workaround like `@="cmd /c copy %1 NewFolder"` is shaky and differ from user expectation (what if %1 is a folder? scary cmd prompt asking whether to overwrite?)

Comment: Ok, it cannot be done. I will check this as the answer, but it does not achieve the original goal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: See updated answer. You may manually construct target to folder this way. It also handles the case when %1 is folder and prompt to overwrite with standard GUI.

Comment: Wow! I never knew about the `Subcommands` parameter!