# Windows "send to" context menu with subfolders

Tags: windows, context-menu, send-to

I'm looking for solution to implement sub-folders in windows "SendTo" context menu.
I'm aware of:
[Can sub-folders be created on the Explorer context "send to" menu](https://superuser.com/questions/1100973/can-sub-folders-be-created-on-the-explorer-context-send-to-menu)
However, this solution doesn't work if source/destination folders have spaces, and I'm unable to rewrite it to work in that case.
My aim is to be able to have either custom context menu with subfolders I can "send to" selected files, or have subfolders in the windows built-in "send to" contextmenu.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you mean `@="wscript C:\\copy.js %1 \"C:\\New Folder\""` doesn't work when there are spaces, try enclosing `%1` in quotes: `\"%1\"`

Comment: perfect, simple solution, thank you very much